# HTTPS and HSTS on Apache/mod_wsgi and Django

Tags: django, apache, security, https, hsts

I'm setting up site-wide HTTPS for my Django 1.8 project. I am not experienced in web security.

I'm setting up HTTP to HTTPS redirect and HSTS.

Right now, I was configuring this on my Apache/mod_wsgi Web Server (I'm using a PaaS so I configure it through the .htaccess file on the WSGI root):

**wsgi/.htaccess**

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Add HSTS header
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"

# Deny rendering inside an iframe
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
```

As per the Django official docs SSL [recommendations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/security/#ssl-https), I'm securing the cookies in my production settings:

**settings/prod.py**

```
...
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
...
```

Note: I'm not setting `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = (“HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO”, “https”)` yet, because I'm not sure yet if the PaaS is proxying and stripping this header between the proxy and the web container.

Django (as of 1.8) now comes with it's [security middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware)(from old django-secure), which implements SSL redirects, and handles HSTS header and other nice things.

**Should I let Django handle all of the HTTPS redirect/HSTS configurations, or do it at the web server level? What are the security/performance implications of each choice?**

References read/used:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

https://garron.net/crypto/hsts/hsts-2013.pdf

https://cipherli.st/

https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8964/trying-to-make-a-django-based-site-use-https-only-not-sure-if-its-secure

http://www.marinamele.com/2014/09/security-on-django-app-https-everywhere.html

https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_for_Apache_NGINX_and_Lighttpd.html

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/security/

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since you've asked the question. Anyway, I faced similar doubts. [The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#ssl-https) is ambiguous whether we should enable HSTS at the app level or on a web server:

> HSTS may either be configured with SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS, SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS, and SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD, or on the Web server.

[The deployment checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/) (`manage.py check --deploy`) suggests to set [SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS) on production.

On the other hand, [Django book](https://djangobook.com/ssl-https-django/) states:

> HSTS is usually configured on the web server.

Considering security, both server set up and django middleware do the same thing. They set up "Strict-Transport-Security" in response Header. I believe that web servers have a better performance than django middleware, though I haven't tested it.

Also, [Two Scoops of Django](https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-11) suggests that it is better to put HTTPS redirects settings to a web server:

> Performance-wise, it’s better to do this at the web server level (p. 347)