# OS environment variables for Django SSL Support

Tags: django, ssl, https, mod-wsgi

While setting up my Django 1.8 project with SSL support on my PaaS (running Apache/mod_wsgi), I used this [community wiki answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/8970/83083) as reference.

However, it states that there should be two environment variables set, on the wsgi.py script and settings.py respectively:

**wsgi.py**

```
os.environ['HTTPS'] = "on"
```

**settings.py**

```
os.environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'https'
```

From what I could gather, the previous `HTTPS` env variable was used by the is_secure method (previously in `django/http/__init__.py` and now moved to `django/http/request.py`) and it seems to have been changed to use the url_scheme as a single control variable (see [code](https://github.com/django/django/blame/master/django/http/request.py#L205)).

So I'm guessing that I would only need to set the `wsgi.url_scheme`, as required by _get_scheme [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py#L115), but do I really? Django's [security SSL section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/security/#ssl-https) and [security middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.security) docs make no reference to it, which makes me think that Django may now be doing it automagically. Or maybe it's outside it's scope.

**So should I set `wsgi.url_scheme` to `https` if I want SSL properly configured in Django?**

Comment: In your setup, where does SSL termination happen?

Comment: Hi @ThomasOrozco, I'm not sure actually. I'm expecting that the request will be routed still encrypted from the Apache process to Django, so I'm guessing Django will terminate the SSL layer. But it's an uninformed guess. I've also asked a question related to the same SSL setup [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32405869/765705), it may help.

Comment: I have the same question, did you ever figure it out ?

Comment: hey @Deuce ! I think I just switched to NOT terminate the SSL connection at the WSGI level but at the web server level (in this case it would be in Apache, but could be Nginx, etc) - because we switched away from that PaaS platform to AWS EC2 and just seemed more sensible to leave that stuff at the web server level.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I ended up doing it at the Apache level as well